# Función UDF procesa correctamente pero dispara un error al devolver un vector demasiado grande

Tags: excel, vba, función-personalizada

Tengo una función para armar un rango para la función de Excel `PERCENTIL.INC`, la misma procesa toda la data en forma correcta, pero al regresar el vector da error (`VALOR!`). He logrado detectar que se debe a que el vector que regresa es de mas de 79.000 registros, creo que esa es la causa del error

¿Hay alguna manera de ampliar el stack?

El código es el siguiente:

```vb
' Función Que regresa el Vector Monto Facturado o Monto Pagado (De acuerdo a lo que se re-
' quiera en base a los parámetros, Edad, Tipo, Tipo Servicio y Sexo, Se usan los vectores
' Tipo, Tipo Servico, Monto Facturado (o Pagado) y Sexo. Todo para ordenar y extraer en
' Base a la edad
' Se Agrega el par{ametro UsoEdad, que es para restringir el uso o no de la edad como
' elemento de selección. Opera de la siguiente manera: Si es cero (0) se prescinde de
' la Edad como elemento de selección{on, cualquier otro valor toma la edad como elemento
' de selección.
' Tomar en cuenta que se crea una variable TMP con 200.000 posiciones, si la tabla (hoja)
' excede ese número hay que incrementar las posiciones
Public Function VctPercentil(UsoEdad As Integer, Edad As Integer, Tipo As Integer, _
        TpoSrv As Integer, Sexo As Integer, vEdad As Range, vTipo As Range, _
        vTipoSrv As Range, vMtoFact As Range, vSexo As Range) As Double()
    Dim LinInE      As Long
    Dim Tmp(200000) As Double
    Dim I, N, K     As Long

    Dim Rsl() As Double
    Dim Trx   As String

    ' Obtenemos el número de filas y columnas del rango seleccionado
    LinInE = vEdad.Rows.Count


    'Obtener vector (UsoEdad=0 Significa No tomar en cuenta la edad)
    If UsoEdad <> 0 Then
        For I = 1 To LinInE
            If vEdad(I, 1) = Edad Then
                If Tipo = 3 Then                                        ' Todos
                    If TpoSrv <= 3 And vTipoSrv(I, 1) = TpoSrv Then     ' Es individual (1 = Elect, 2= No elect. 3=Amb)
                        If Sexo = 2 Then                                ' Ambos sexos
                            Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                        ElseIf vSexo(I, 1) = Sexo Then                  ' Sexos separados
                            Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                        End If
                    ElseIf TpoSrv = 4 And (vTipoSrv(I, 1) = 1 Or vTipoSrv(I, 1) = 2) Then   ' Combinación Electivas y no electivas
                        If Sexo = 2 Then                                ' Ambos sexos
                            Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                        ElseIf vSexo(I, 1) = Sexo Then                  ' Sexos separados
                            Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                        End If
                    ElseIf TpoSrv = 5 Then                             ' Combinación todos
                        If Sexo = 2 Then                                ' Ambos sexos
                            Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                        ElseIf vSexo(I, 1) = Sexo Then                  ' Sexos separados
                            Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                        End If
                    End If
                ElseIf Tipo = 1 And vTipo(I, 1) = Tipo Then             ' Activos
                    If TpoSrv <= 3 And vTipoSrv(I, 1) = TpoSrv Then     ' Es individual (1 = Elect, 2= No elect. 3=Amb)
                        If Sexo = 2 Then                                ' Ambos sexos
                            Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                        ElseIf vSexo(I, 1) = Sexo Then                  ' Sexos separados
                            Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                        End If
                    ElseIf TpoSrv = 4 Then                              ' Combinación Electivas y no electivas
                        If Sexo = 2 Then                                ' Ambos sexos
                            Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                        ElseIf vSexo(I, 1) = Sexo Then                  ' Sexos separados
                            Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                        End If
                    ElseIf TpoSrv = 5 Then                              ' Combinación todos
                        If Sexo = 2 Then                                ' Ambos sexos
                            Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                        ElseIf vSexo(I, 1) = Sexo Then                  ' Sexos separados
                            Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                        End If
                    End If
                ElseIf Tipo = 2 And vTipo(I, 1) = Tipo Then            ' Inactivos
                    If TpoSrv <= 3 And vTipoSrv(I, 1) = TpoSrv Then     ' Es individual (1 = Elect, 2= No elect. 3=Amb)
                        If Sexo = 2 Then                                ' Ambos sexos
                            Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                        ElseIf vSexo(I, 1) = Sexo Then                  ' Sexos separados
                            Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                        End If
                    ElseIf TpoSrv = 4 Then                              ' Combinación Electivas y no electivas
                        If Sexo = 2 Then                                ' Ambos sexos
                            Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                        ElseIf vSexo(I, 1) = Sexo Then                  ' Sexos separados
                            Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                        End If
                    ElseIf TpoSrv = 5 Then                              ' Combinación todos
                        If Sexo = 2 Then                                ' Ambos sexos
                            Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                        ElseIf vSexo(I, 1) = Sexo Then                  ' Sexos separados
                            Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Else
        For I = 1 To LinInE
            If Tipo = 3 Then                                        ' Todos
                If TpoSrv <= 3 And vTipoSrv(I, 1) = TpoSrv Then     ' Es individual (1 = Elect, 2= No elect. 3=Amb)
                    If Sexo = 2 Then                                ' Ambos sexos
                        Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                    ElseIf vSexo(I, 1) = Sexo Then                  ' Sexos separados
                        Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                    End If
                ElseIf TpoSrv = 4 And (vTipoSrv(I, 1) = 1 Or vTipoSrv(I, 1) = 2) Then   ' Combinación Electivas y no electivas
                    If Sexo = 2 Then                                ' Ambos sexos
                        Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                    ElseIf vSexo(I, 1) = Sexo Then                  ' Sexos separados
                        Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                    End If
                ElseIf TpoSrv = 5 Then                             ' Combinación todos
                    If Sexo = 2 Then                                ' Ambos sexos
                        Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                    ElseIf vSexo(I, 1) = Sexo Then                  ' Sexos separados
                        Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                    End If
                End If
            ElseIf Tipo = 1 And vTipo(I, 1) = Tipo Then             ' Activos
                If TpoSrv <= 3 And vTipoSrv(I, 1) = TpoSrv Then     ' Es individual (1 = Elect, 2= No elect. 3=Amb)
                    If Sexo = 2 Then                                ' Ambos sexos
                        Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                    ElseIf vSexo(I, 1) = Sexo Then                  ' Sexos separados
                        Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                    End If
                ElseIf TpoSrv = 4 Then                              ' Combinación Electivas y no electivas
                    If Sexo = 2 Then                                ' Ambos sexos
                        Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                    ElseIf vSexo(I, 1) = Sexo Then                  ' Sexos separados
                        Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                    End If
                ElseIf TpoSrv = 5 Then                              ' Combinación todos
                    If Sexo = 2 Then                                ' Ambos sexos
                        Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                    ElseIf vSexo(I, 1) = Sexo Then                  ' Sexos separados
                        Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                    End If
                End If
            ElseIf Tipo = 2 And vTipo(I, 1) = Tipo Then            ' Inactivos
                If TpoSrv <= 3 And vTipoSrv(I, 1) = TpoSrv Then     ' Es individual (1 = Elect, 2= No elect. 3=Amb)
                    If Sexo = 2 Then                                ' Ambos sexos
                        Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                    ElseIf vSexo(I, 1) = Sexo Then                  ' Sexos separados
                        Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                    End If
                ElseIf TpoSrv = 4 Then                              ' Combinación Electivas y no electivas
                    If Sexo = 2 Then                                ' Ambos sexos
                        Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                    ElseIf vSexo(I, 1) = Sexo Then                  ' Sexos separados
                        Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                    End If
                ElseIf TpoSrv = 5 Then                              ' Combinación todos
                    If Sexo = 2 Then                                ' Ambos sexos
                        Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                    ElseIf vSexo(I, 1) = Sexo Then                  ' Sexos separados
                        Tmp(I) = vMtoFact.Cells(I, 1)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
    ' Hallar dimensión vector resultante
    On Error GoTo ErrA
    Open "MGT.txt" For Output As #1
    N = 0
    For I = 1 To LinInE
        If Tmp(I) <> 0 Then
            N = N + 1
        End If
    Next
    If N <> 0 Then
        ReDim Rsl(N - 1)

        ' Almacenar en vector resultante
        K = 0
        For I = 1 To LinInE
            If Tmp(I) <> 0 Then
                Rsl(K) = Tmp(I)
                Write #1, Rsl(K)
                K = K + 1
            End If
        Next
        VctPercentil = Rsl
    Else
        ReDim Rsl(0)
        Tmp(0) = 0
        Rsl(0) = Tmp(1)
        VctPercentil = Rsl
    End If
    Close #1
    Exit Function
ErrA:
    Debug.Print Error, Err
End Function
```

La linea con la instrucción `Open` la agregué para generar un archivo y verificar que toda la data era procesada, así mismo la instrucción `ON ERROR` la agregué para verificar que no había error en la parte álgida de la función (Y no lo hay), el error se produce en el `return (VctPercentil = Rsl)`.

No tengo ningún inconveniente en enviar una hoja resumen con toda la data y el código.

Comment: Hola Maximiliano. Bienvenido!!! Te podré pedir más información de lo que preguntás? En particular: ¿Qué función? Por favor incluí el código bien formateado, así nos damos una idea de los que estás haciendo. Por otro lado, está devolviendo un rango a lo ancho o a lo alto (Excel no tiene los mismos límites para horizontal o vertical). Sería bueno que pudieras [edit] la pregunta agregando esta información

Comment: En el contexto de Excel, una función personalizada se utiliza en una fórmula y esta tiene ciertas limitaciones como el uso de métodos CELLS. Más que una función personalizada parece que se trata de una macro o un procedimientos (sub procedure) Referencia [Descripción de las limitaciones de las funciones personalizadas en Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/es-mx/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel). Por otro lado el código es demasiado grande, en su lugar debería incluirse un [mcve], además que faltan detalles como la versión de Excel y del sistema operativo.